# I cannot login to own ClueReleaseManager site

Tags: python, authentication, pypi, werkzeug, repoze.who

I have setup my own pypi server, using the [ClueReleaseManager framework](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ClueReleaseManager), and I defined a user (for testing purposes only) as follows:

```
 cluerelmgr-admin updateuser test test test@localhost
```

Then I started the server with

```
cluerelmgr-server -p 8081
```

and tried to login on the site `localhost:8081` as `test` with password `test`. It does not work! I am unable to login as user `test` - the login window just pops up again.

`ClueReleaseManager` seems to use  `werkzeug` 0.4.1 and `repoze-who` 1.0.19. Any idea on how to fix this problem are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue whilst playing around with *ClueReleaseManager*. The solution was as simple as ***restarting the server and clearing the cache***.

FYI, this is the list of packages and their versions that I used;

```
ClueReleaseManager==0.3.3
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.18
Paste==1.7.5.1
SQLAlchemy==0.9.2
Werkzeug==0.4.1
docutils==0.11
repoze.who==1.0.19
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.0.5
```